# Загрузка изображения при условии обязательных кликов на два других изображения

Tags: javascript

Есть изображения:
1.
2.
3.
Нужно чтобы загрузилось изображение 3.
Для этого нужно обязательно сделать клик на изображение 1 и 2 и только после этого должно появиться изображение 3. 
Как это сделать в JS?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: вопрос который подразумевает сделайте за меня минусуется. Приведите код где у Вас возникла проблема

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var statusone = false;
var statustwo = false;

function one() {
  statusone = true;
  if (statusone === true && statustwo === true) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("square3")[0].style = "opacity: 1";
  }
}

function two() {
  statustwo = true;
  if (statusone === true && statustwo === true) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("square3")[0].style = "opacity: 1";
  }
}
```

```css
.square3 {
  opacity: 0;
}

[class^=square] {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 88px;
  width: 88px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square1" onClick="one()"></div>
<div class="square2" onClick="two()"></div>
<div class="square3"></div>
```